# Is there a cheap and effective way to make PdZn-Ag foam?

Tags: hydrocarbons, nanotechnology, silver, carbon-dioxide

I am trying to design a machine that can convert carbon dioxide into methanol and/or hydrocarbons. My design requires PdZn-Ag foam (nanoparticles), which is made by depositing palladium-zinc vapor onto a silver base, but this seems to be very costly. So is there is a cheap and effective way of producing a measurable amount of PdZn-Ag foam?

Comment: Palladium is not cheap!

Comment: Perhaps an alloy would help?

Comment: I need around 3-4 g of palladium.